# Print "no patch" when there is no more patches to occupy

Tags: netlogo

I want to print "no path" when there is no more patches to occupy instead of warned by an Error "MOVE-TO expected input to be an agent but got NOBODY instead.". I did several things but did not work. Lastly, I did the following;

```
 ask migrants
  [let pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
   let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
    if target = 0 [print (word "no patch")]
    if (target != 0 and (status != "resident")) [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                              set status "resident"
                                              set color blue]


  ]
```

Here is the complete code

```
breed [migrants migrant]
breed [residents resident]

patches-own [value]
turtles-own [income
status]

to setup
  ca
  let total problo + probmid + probhi
  if (total != 100) 
     [print (word "prob is more than 100")]
  ask patches [set value random-normal 10 3
  let patch-value value
    set pcolor scale-color (gray - 5) patch-value 10 3]
  ask patches
  [if random 100 < 3
    [sprout-residents 1
      [set color red
       set shape "default"
       set size 1
       set status "resident"   
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to go

  ask patches 
  [if random 100 < 1 
    [sprout-migrants 1
      [set color green
       set shape "default"
       set size 1 
        set status "migrant"
       set-move 
  ]]]

end

to set-move
 ask migrants
  [let pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
   let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
    if target = 0 [print (word "no patch")]
    if (target != 0 and (status != "resident")) [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                              set status "resident"
                                              set color blue]


  ] 

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up an agentset and the `count` of the agents in that agentset. This line:

```
let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
```

returns an agentset. So your variable "target" is all the patches that meet your conditions. If there are no patches that meet your conditions, then the agentset is not 0, but the `count` of the agentset is.

So you need to replace `if target = 0 [print (word "no patch")]` with `if count target = 0 [print (word "no patch")]` or with `if not any? [print (word "no patch")]`.

Comment: Thanks JenB. It worked actually. But I thought if  "count target = 0 [print (word "no patch")] " works it will end the simulation but it keeps going. I think I need to post a new question for this right?